# Seeking nice proof of $ \frac {(ab-1)(bc-1)(ca-1)} {(a^2-1)(b^2-1)(c^2-1)} < \frac 9 8$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

> The inequality $$ 1 < \frac {(ab-1)(bc-1)(ca-1)} {(a^2-1)(b^2-1)(c^2-1)} < \frac 9 8 $$ is true if $3 \le a<b<c$.

The lower bound is quite easy.

For the upper bound let $a=x+3,b=y+3,c=z+3$ and expand 9 $\times$ denominator $-$ 8 $\times$ numerator to get a positive constant and 20 terms each a positive coefficient times some power of $x$, $y$ and $z$.

**Question**: Is there a "nicer" proof?

Comment: Any information about this problem e.g. source?

Comment: This arose from studying Lenstra & Pomerance's "Remarks on Agrawal's Conjecture". Specifically, find four distinct numbers (not necessarily prime) $p_i$ so that for all $i$ $p_i - 1 \ | \ p_1 p_2 p_3 p_4 - 1$ and $p_i + 1 \ | \ p_1 p_2 p_3 p_4 + 1$. (I proved that the case of three numbers has no solution.)

Comment: Thanks. It is interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Per your request, for the right inequality:

Using $3 \le a < b < c$, we have
$$ab - \frac{(bc - 1)(ca - 1)}{c^2 - 1} = \frac{bc + ac - ab - 1}{c^2 - 1} > 0.$$

Using $ab > \frac{(bc - 1)(ca - 1)}{c^2 - 1} > 0$, it suffices to prove that
$$\frac{ab - 1}{(a^2 - 1)(b^2 - 1)} \cdot ab \le \frac{9}{8}$$
or
$$a^2b^2 - 9a^2 + 8ab - 9b^2 + 9 \ge 0$$
or
$$(a^2 - 9)(b^2 - 9) + 8(ab - 9) \ge 0$$
which is true.

We are done.

Comment: +1, but can you provide some insight on the auxiliary inequality? Also, the last inequality becomes equality when $a=b=c=3$, which seem to leave a lot of room of improvement in the first inequality, so it looks like better bounds are possible.

Comment: I take back the "loose" part. After a closer examination, if $a=3, b=n, c=n+1$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac {(ab-1)(bc-1)(ca-1)} {(a^2-1)(b^2-1)(c^2-1)}=\frac{9}{8}$, so it seems that indeed it can be made as close to $\frac{9}{8}$ as wanted by increasing the distance between $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @Momo Thanks. I tried $a = b =3$ to get $\frac{(3c - 1)^2}{8(c^2 - 1)} \to 9/8$ as $c \to \infty$. So I considered the terms containing $c$ i.e. $(bc-1)(ca-1)/(c^2-1)$ which is $ab$ as $c\to \infty$. Then I proved $(bc-1)(ca-1)/(c^2-1) < ab$ for all $c>b>a\ge 3$.

Comment: @Momo The lower bound $1$ is also attained when $a = b  = c $ (any real number larger than 3). The upper bound $9/8$ is also attained when $a = 3, b = c \to \infty$. These constant bounds are best.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in another way with backwards.
I don’t know it is a nicer proof.
but this is beautiful for me.
(sorry for my bad English).
[image: backward]

Comment: $(ab-1)(bc-1)(ca-1) < (a^2-1)(b^2-1)(c^2-1)$ is not true, e.g. when $a = 3, b = 4, c = 5$.

Comment: oh sorry my mistake

Comment: By the way, I did not downvote you. Someone downvoted you and me before (almost the same time).